# WPF Desktop and web service in same solution

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services

I am revising .NET and web services and attempting to test calling the web service I created with a WPF desktop application.  The web service builds and runs fine and when I start without debugging in VS Community 2017 it works as expected and I can see the web service end points in the browser along with the WSDL.  But when I attempt to add a WPF desktop application and start without debugging to the browser does NOT have the .asmx file in the URL anymore and states -

HTTP Error 403.14 Forbidden
the web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory

I have googled this error and tried several of the suggested fixes but none of them have resolved the issue.  Can this be done at all or do I have to publish the web service to IIS Express on its own and have the WPF desktop application on its own?  Its just that it would be very useful to have a desktop application within the same solution to code and test

Comment: What happens if you right-click each project and Debug -> Start new instance?

Comment: Are you able to discover the service when it is running in non debug mode (using Ctrl +F5)?

Comment: You have to start both project. Right click on the solution > select set startup projects > select multiple startup project > set both project to start